# Create select DOM object with options in jQuery, Passing Attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I create a select DOM object with options in jquery similar to this input creation example?

```
$('<input />', {
  name: 'age',
  type: 'number',
  placeholder: 'enter a number 1'
}).appendTo('#app');
```

Is there a way to create it passing attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an element with jQuery, any attribute, or even jQuery method, can be used in the options object, so you can do

```js
$('<select />', {
  name   : 'test',
  on     : {
      change : function() { /* stuff */ }
  },
  append : [
      $('<option />', {value : "1", text : "Opt 1"}),
      $('<option />', {value : "2", text : "Opt 2"}),
      $('<option />', {value : "3", text : "Opt 3"})
  ]
}).appendTo('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create just by passing the entire select with option as string

```
$('<select name="number">' +
  '<option>1</option>' +
  '<option>2</option>' +
  '<option>3</option>' +
'</select>').appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using an array of objects having the required `value` and `text` and creating new select element based on the array information.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var arrSelect = [
  { value: 1, text: 'One' },
  { value: 2, text: 'Two' },
  { value: 3, text: 'Three' }
 ];

 var select = $('<select>').appendTo('body'); //Create new select element
  
 //Loop through the array of objects and then create new option and append to select element
 arrSelect.map(function (arr) { select.append($("<option>").attr('value', arr.value).text(arr.text)) });
  
 $("body").append(select); //Append select to body element
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1_ you can select Multiple DOM  [`Multi DOM Select`](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

like so :

```
$( "div, .sCLASS, p.myClass" ).whatever...
```

2_ you can also select Single DOM with concate [`Single DOM Select`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-elements-when-i-already-have-a-dom-element/)

like so :

```
$( "p" + ".sCLASS" ).whatever...
```

BUT you can't pass arg with it

Comment: check this https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/jquery-14-released-the-15-new-features-you-must-know--net-8590

Comment: Page Not Found, provide valid link Please!! then i'll get my Wrong(if so) idea Thanks

Comment: try again please

Answer (score 0):

The object select is created and then the options objects are appended.

```
$('<select />', {
  id: 'my-numbers',
  name: 'select-number'
})
.append($("<option/>", {
    value: '1',
    text: 'number1'
}))
.append($("<option/>", {
    value: '2',
    text: 'number2'
}))
.appendTo('#app');
```